# Xamarin SQLite Query

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I try to create a query in the shard project in xamarin.

I can successfully create a connection to my local DB with dependecy services. But I'm not able to create a query.

Here is my code:

Connection to DB(successfully)

```
SQLite.SQLiteConnection DBConnection = DependencyService.Get<IDBHelper>().DbConnection(DBPath);
```

Get table Info (successfully)

```
var TableInfo = DBConnection.GetTableInfo("SomeTableName");
```

Query (failed)

```
var ReturnValue = DBConnection.Query<string>("Select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like 'Value'");
```

Viusal Studio shows me the problem, its the `<string>` part. But I have no idea what I have to change.

How can I create a simple select query?

Comment: "Viusal Studio shows me the problem" - what specifically does it say?  What is the specific error message or exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the SQLite-Net package. This works like an ORM over SQLite database.

The generic part (where you did put `<string>`) is the type of object that the query must expect when getting results.

It will automatically turn the resultset into a list of your queried type.

As you are querying all data from the `SomeTable` table each row will represent a `SomeTable` object (I guess you have created such class).

Just change this line to:

```
var ReturnValue = DBConnection.Query<SomeTable>("Select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like 'Value'");
```

or

```
var ReturnValue = DBConnection.Query<object>("Select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like 'Value'");
```

You can get a step by step using SQLite at the [official sqlite-net documentation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I had to create a class for "SomeTable"